# How to access MySql or Postgres databases in rider IDE Using C# .net for console application?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, npgsql, rider

when I tried to import library clases for postgres to connect with database.
It says can not find name Npgsql.

using Npgsql;

[image]

I have installed .Net core 5.0.202 and mono 6.12.0.122
and I am using ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 1):

Did you installed the postgres nuget package ?

Postgresql package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/

How to install:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-dotnet-cli

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I resolved this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I resolved this problem. I did setting for that in build, execution and deployment. And then downloaded Nuget package and installed for the project. And now its working.